# Why is a Docker container still running even after I deleted the image, container, and shutdown Docker itself?

Tags: docker, containers

After I installed Docker, I went through its docker/getting-started tutorial.

I've stopped the container, deleted the image and container (using docker ps -a and docker images -a to ensure I've done it correctly) and even shutdown the Docker engine. Yet, whenever I travel to localhost it still directs me to http://localhost/tutorial/ where I still see the getting started tutorial.

What is wrong?

Comment: What happens if you CTRL + F5 (force refresh from server) it? Could be simply cached

Comment: @SiHa  This worked! Thanks, I didn't know to try that.